# Why Python's requests transforms parts of source code?

Tags: python, html

I am trying to scrape through google news search results using python's `requests` to get links to different articles. I get the links by using `Beautiful Soup`.

The problem I get is that although in browser's source view all links look normal, after the operation they are changed - all of the start with "/url?q=" and after the "core" of the link is finished there goes a string of characters which starts with "&". Also - some characters inside the link are also changed - for example url:

http://www.azonano.com/news.aspx?newsID=35576

changes to:

http://www.azonano.com/news.aspx%newsID%35576

I'm using standard "getting started" code:

```
import requests, bs4


url_list = list()
url = 'https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&gl=us&tbm=nws&authuser=0&q=graphene&oq=graphene&gs_l=news-cc.3..43j0l9j43i53.2022.4184.0.4322.14.10.3.1.1.1.166.884.5j5.10.0...0.0...1ac.1.-Q2j3YFqIPQ'
res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

for link in soup.select('h3 > a'):                 
       url_list.append(link.get('href'))

# First link on google news page is: 
# https://www.theengineer.co.uk/graphene-sensor-could-speed-hepatitis-diagnosis/

print url_list[0] #this line will print url modified by requests.
```

I know it's possible to get around this problem by using `selenium`, but I'd like to know where lies a root cause of this problem with `requests` (or more plausible not with `requests` but the way I'm using it).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Present a [MCVE] that we can actually see the problem.

Comment: The source code originally actually looks like that, and is actually changed dynamically to what you see in your browser's element inspector by Javascript. Use *View Source* (no, not "inspect element", but *View Source*) to corroborate.

Comment: @deceze - When I use  _View Source_ I still see the same links (unchanged)

[link](view-source:https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&gl=us&tbm=nws&authuser=0&q=graphene&oq=graphene&gs_l=news-cc.3..43j0l9j43i53.2022.4184.0.4322.14.10.3.1.1.1.166.884.5j5.10.0...0.0...1ac.1.-Q2j3YFqIPQ)  - when I look for azonano links, they still have "?", "=" chars.

Comment: Google may be serving different HTML based on the user agent, I don't know. Fact is, `requests` most certainly isn't changing anything, it's giving you the HTML it's receiving from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing what you are seeing with a browser with what requests generates (i.e. there is no user agent header). If you specify this before making the initial request it will reflect what you would see in a web browser. Google serves the requests differently it looks like:

```
url = 'https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&gl=us&tbm=nws&authuser=0&q=graphene&oq=graphene&gs_l=news-cc.3..43j0l9j43i53.2022.4184.0.4322.14.10.3.1.1.1.166.884.5j5.10.0...0.0...1ac.1.-Q2j3YFqIPQ'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'} # I just used a general Chrome 41 user agent header
res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```